# No consigo ver el código en el navegador

Tags: php, poo

Tengo el siguiente anunciado, pero ni siquiera consigo que se muestre en el navegador, y nose donde esta el fallo..

Y como se hace en php para que el usuario pueda seleccionar lo que quiere?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?php

class coche{

  private $color;
  private $numero_puertas;
  private $marca;
  private $gasolina;



function llenarDeposito($cantidad){
    $this->cantidad = $gasolina;
}

function acelerar(){
  if($gasolina == 0){
    echo "Imposible acelerar";
  }
  else{
    this->$gasolina--;
  }
}


}

$coche = new coche();

$coche->llenarDeposito(20);
echo "El diposito tiene " .$coche->llenarDeposito();

$coche->acelerar();
$coche->acelerar();
$coche->acelerar();


echo "<br/> Gasolina actual: ".$coche->acelerar();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aún no tienes claro los conceptos básicos de la POO. Te recomiendo que busques un par de tutoriales (*o dile a tu profe que enseñe bien*). Te dejo un ejemplo **básico** de lo que necesitas.

```php
<?php
// la definición de la tu clase
class Coche
{
    private $color;
    private $numero_puertas;
    private $marca;
    private $gasolina = 0;

    public function llenarDeposito($cantidad = null)
    {
        if ($cantidad) {
            $this->gasolina = $this->gasolina + $cantidad;
        }
    }

    public function acelerar()
    {
        if ($this->gasolina == 0) {
            echo 'Imposible acelerar. No hay gasolina <br>';
            return -1;
        }

        // descuenta gasolina
        $this->gasolina--;

        // retorna lo que queda
        return $this->gasolina;
    }

}


// crear instancia de la clase Coche y utilizarla
if ($_POST['ejecutar']) {

    $cantidadGasolina      = $_POST['cantidadGasolina'] ?? 1;
    $cantidadAceleraciones = $_POST['cantidadAceleraciones'] ?? 1;

    $coche = new Coche();

    echo "Llenando deposito... con $cantidadGasolina de gasolina<br>";
    $coche->llenarDeposito($cantidadGasolina);

    for ($i=0; $i < $cantidadAceleraciones; $i++) {

        $acelerar = $coche->acelerar();

        if ($acelerar != -1) {
            echo "Acelerando... gasolina actual: {$acelerar} <br>";
        } else {
            break; // evita que siga ejecutándose sin gasolina
        }
    }

}


// un formulario para que el usuario seleccione lo que quiere hacer
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ui</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="cantidadGasolina" value="<?php echo $cantidadGasolina ?? 1;?>">
        <input type="text" name="cantidadAceleraciones" value="<?php echo $cantidadAceleraciones ?? 1;?>">

        <button name="ejecutar" value="run">Ejecutar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No he probado tu código, pero veo que hay cosas que estás haciendo al revés.

Las propiedades/atributos de una clase van precedidas de $this, pero no los parámetros de funciones u otras variables.

```
    function llenarDeposito($cantidad){
         $cantidad = $this->gasolina;
    }

    function acelerar(){
         if($this->gasolina == 0){
              echo "Imposible acelerar";
         }
         else{
              $this->gasolina--;
         }
    }
```